# Redirect to default homepage in a Wifi Network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router

Is there a way to set a default homepage for a Wifi Network, maybe tweaking the router configuration? My router is TP-Link TL-WR541G.

I mean, when someone just connects to the wifi and first open the browser.

Chillispot is a close solution. However, I only need to redirect WLAN hosts to a public web page when they open the browser for first time, not for login or revenue stuff.

Comment: The site structure relies on questions containing just the question and solutions being in answer posts.  Your solution was moved to an answer.  If you accept that (or any other answer), that will signify that the issue has been solved.

Answer (score 11):

You'll want/need to implement a captive portal. See here for a description:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal

Comment: This is what I was looking for. The magic of superuser.

Answer (score 3):

In order to route my Wi-Fi traffic to a local web page which shows :

> **Yes, it works!**

,I am using Linux IPTABLES:

```
#iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.1:80
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, this functionality can only be provided by the router that provides the actual gateway to the web.  Consumer-grade routers generally don't provide this functionality.

However, some inexpensive consumer-grade routers can have their firmware replaced with something much more powerful.  [DD-WRT](https://secure.dd-wrt.com/) is one example.  Unfortunately, it appears that your specific router isn't supported.

If you choose to get a different router and play with DD-WRT, then you can set up a Captive Portal using [Chillispot](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Chillispot).

Good luck :)

Comment: thanks for the info! I read a little about captive portals, that's seems the option, although I don't need any authentication

Comment: Hello again. I'm about to install DD-WRT on a compatible router. I'll try Chillispot, but I must say I just want the browser to redirect to a public web page, not for login or revenue stuff. Do you think it will be possible using some captative portal?

Answer (score 1):

Posted by the OP in the question and moved to an answer post:

> I've solved it using NoDogSplash installed on OpenWRT. Both are very easy to configure. If you're stucked in this, give it a try!